# Rails 5 config.force_ssl blocking access to subdomains that point to a different server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, cookies, dns, ruby-on-rails-5

I am running a rails 5 site with config.force_ssl set to true.  The problem that I am having is that this creates cookies which force SSL on all subdomains, even ones that are not part of the app or hosted on the same server.  For example I have mail.example.com which has its DNS pointed at google and blog.example.com has it's DNS pointed to NameCheap servers.  The cookie created by config.force_ssl redirects both of these to https and thereby blocks access to those pages.

Based on the [ActionDispatch::SSL](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/SSL.html) documentation I can see that this is intended behavior and apparently there's a way to add exclusions to the ssl_options based on this example:

```
config.ssl_options = { redirect: { exclude: -> request { request.path =~ /healthcheck/ } } }
```

I'm trying to get this to work with the subdomains mentioned, but it's not working.  The same cookie is set and I am once again blocked from those subdomains.  Maybe I'm not doing this right.  Here is the line:

```
config.ssl_options = { redirect: { exclude: -> request { request.subdomain =~ /mail|link|blog/ } } }
```

Alternatively, is there another way I should be doing this?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find a solution to this?  There's probably some strange browser/operating system caching going on here since somehow headers sent browsing the website on one subdomain affect mail servers accessing a different subdomain, so maybe it just started working...

Comment: Looks like the new_framework_defaults initializer is the right place for this now, and the default includes instructions on how to disable subdomains.

Comment: I ended up doing force_ssl on the controller level which isn't as secure, but allowed me to have subdomains outside of ssl.  here's a post about it: http://www.eq8.eu/blogs/14-config-force_ssl-is-different-than-controller-force_ssl.  Did you figure out a solution using config.ssl_options?  That really is the better way to go.